# How to get body of a response as a string?

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs

I have an HTTP service that just requests data from the server and returns a result.
During development of my project different errors may occur on the server, and it doesn't always return JSON, so I need to get the body of a response as a string.

I have this piece of code that requests data:

```
getVersions(entryURLName: string) {
    return this._http.get('/ajax/entry/' + entryURLName + '/versions')
      .map((response: Response) => <Version[]>response.json())
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And in the error handler I have this:

```
handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log(error);

    var errorMessage;
    try {
      let errorObj = error.json().error;
      errorMessage = errorObj;
    } catch (e) {
      errorMessage = error.text();
    }

    return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
}
```

I've read in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html) that `Response` object has `text()` method that returns the body as a string, but actually the `error` variable here doesn't have this method. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**Update #1**:

Here's what `console.log(error);` prints (Safari): 
[image]

Comment: What does `console.log(error);` print?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Updated my question. Here's the screenshot from Safari console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage the `Content-Type` header to know to extract the data from the payload:

```
getVersions(entryURLName: string) {
  return this._http.get('/ajax/entry/' + entryURLName + '/versions')
  .map((response: Response) => {
     if (response.headers['Content-Type']==='application/json') {
       return <Version[]>response.json();
     } else {
       return response.text();
     }
   })
  .do(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Same for the error callback.

In your case, I think that there is a problem in your `map` callback and it throws an error you get in the `catch` callback (instead of the response itself).